# Ambiguous definition of compactness

Tags: real-analysis

Rosenlicht defines compactness as:

"A subset $S$ of a metric space $E$ is *compact* if, whenever $S$ is contained in the union of a collection of open subsets of $E$, then $S$ is contained in the union of a finite number of these open subsets."

I might be missing something here, but doesn't that mean *any* subset that can be contained in a union of a finite number of open subsets is compact? That just seems off to me, and I've seen many other definitions of compactness that aren't even remotely close to Rosenlicht's

Could someone give me an intuitive understanding of compactness, and give me an example and a counter example?

Comment: Apart from the absence of the term "open cover" this is the usual definition of compactness.

Comment: An open cover of $S$ is any collection of open subsets of $E$ such that for any $s$ in $S$ there is an open set in the collection which contains $s$.

Comment: with your definition every set would be compact, because it is contained in the metric space that is an open set.

Answer (score 1):

No: the keyword here is *whenever*.

Whenever $S \subset \cup_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}} O_\alpha$ where each $O_\alpha$ is open, then $S\subset \cup_{i=1}^n O_{\alpha_i}$ for some (finite) subcollection $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}\subset{\mathcal{A}}$.

Intuitively, being compact is the *next best thing to being finite*. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, it turns out that every compact set is closed and bounded (like a finite set).