# Why does compactness of a subset in a Euclidean space imply that it is closed and bounded?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm just getting started on topology, and having trouble reconciling with the Heine-Borel Theorem. That is:

For a subset S of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, the following are equivalent:

- S is closed and bounded
- S is compact; that is, every open cover of S has a finite subcover

I've read the proof, but I've managed to get hooked on a "counterexample" that I can't think my way around. Suppose S is some open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then let C be a collection of sets containing just S. Is C then not an open cover of S with a finite subcover (that subcover being C itself)? This would imply that S is both compact and open.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Key word here is *every* open cover must have a finite subcover. There exist open covers of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with no finite subcover. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, consider the interval $(0, 1)$ and the cover $((0, \tfrac{1}{n}))_{n = 1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: It looks like you’re confusing me the quantifiers involved. The definition of compactness does not say “there exists a cover with a finite subcover”. It says “all covers have a finite subcover “. You seem to be doing the former.  In fact I think there are posts on the site where people make the same mistake...

Comment: Here’s [one example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1823318/29335)

Comment: Ahhhhh...that clarifies it greatly. Bit of a rookie error from me, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Tom no problem:  you are definitely not alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've exhibited an example of an open cover with a finite subcover. To show a subset is compact, we must show that **every** open cover admits a finite subcover.

If $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonempty open subset, I claim that we can cook up an example of an open cover with no finite subcover. In particular, this will show that $S$ is not compact.

For $n\geq 1$, define $U_n \subseteq S$ to be
$$U_n =\{ x \in S : d(x, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus S) > 1/n \}.$$
Here, $d(x, T)$ means "the minimal distance between the point $x$ and the set $T$", and is defined precisely as
$$d(x,T) = \inf_{y\in T} d(x,y).$$

In words, $U_n$ is the subset of $S$ consisting of elements that are at least $1/n$ away from the edge of $S$. We have $U_1\subseteq U_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq S$. Eventually, every element of $S$ will fall into some $U_n$, so this is an open cover. If we take a finite subcover, then we will miss some points.

Comment: p.s. I think the $U_n$ I gave are precise, but there is a lot to unpack in the symbols I have written. I would definitely focus on the "in words..." portion, and as is often the case, a sketch of the situation might be helpful :)